# Vue .js dynamic page title

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, single-page-application

Trying to change page title depending on URL params in VueJS project.

In `router` have the folowing path:

```
 {
   path: '/:location',
   name: 'home_spec',
   components: { default: Home, header: StarterNavbar, footer: StarterFooter },
 }
```

and pushing location to title also in router:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.params.location){
    document.title = `${to.params.location}`
  }else{
    document.title = "Default title"
  }
  next()
})
```

in `index.html` have

```
 <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
```

**And it works fine** (tab has desireable title ) **BUT** sourcecode (CTRL+U) has the default title as in the package,js name parameter.

Is it possible to send the first html page with the desirable title in SPA?
If the answer is no, what about SEO is it critical for searching robots?

Comment: the CTRL+U sourcecode is unparsed, raw HTML. So no JavaScript has been executed yet. What usually happens (if you care for SEO) is that the pages are prerendered with something called ServerSide Rendering (SSR).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try another way of setting page title? for example u can do:

```
  {
   path: '/:location',
   name: 'home_spec',
   components: { default: Home, header: StarterNavbar, 
                 footer:StarterFooter },
   meta: { pageTitle: 'example' }

  router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
   document.title = to.meta.title;
   } )
```